# Would methamphetamine heal wounds, infections, and diseases?

Tags: neurology

Alright, so this sounds crazy but based on these research findings it is safe to assume that meth would allow wounds and diseases to heal faster by interleukin 6 . On the otherhand, using meth during illness would cause higher neurotoxicity due to extreme hyperthermia and fever.

Correct me if I'm wrong:

Firstly, [dopamine increases interleukin 6 (IL-6) release and inhibits tumor necrosis factor release](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21307293). 
Interleukin-6 is the source of fevers and hyperthermia. [Most importantly, IL-6 heals skin wounds](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8024036). It's main goal is to regulate the immune system by raising and lowering temperature depending on if a person is sick or not. Raising body temperature will prevent a person from being sick and will make wounds heal faster, but will induce neurotoxicity, lowering it will prevent neurotoxicity but make someone vulnerable to infection. According to Wikipedia, IL-6 stimulates the inflammatory and auto-immune processes in many diseases such as diabetes, atherosclerosis, depression, Alzheimer's Disease (interestingly though, Alzheimer disease is reliant on dopamine depletion, and [people with Alzheimer had significantly higher levels of IL-6](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22026253), which is surprising. One possibility is due to the fact that dopamine increases interleukin 6 release, and without dopamine, IL-6 cant be released, meaning more IL-6 will be metabolized but not used).

IL-6 is also the main, and perhaps only, cause of meth-induced neurotoxicity. It is responsible for neurotoxicity by means including, but not limited to, cell death, ROS generation, and neuronal damage. [Lowering enviromental temprature significantly prevents neurotoxicity](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12706754). To verify this claim, I Googled "methamphetamine neurotoxicity interleukin-6", and came to [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11093760), furthering the evidence that meth vastly potentiates IL-6 and IL-6 induced hyperthermia is the result of meth-induced neurotoxocity, as mice with a mutation for IL-6 blocked meth-induced neurotoxicity, which also means that these mice won't be able to reheal faster.

To bring an update to this post, I have [found this paper that shows that happiness potentiates the immune system](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1568997206000279). But this is a very minor influence as [meth produces >1000 "units" of dopamine, relative to 300 units which cocaine produces](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/meth/body/methbrainnoflash.html). Meth would be much more efficient.

To bring further updates, it seems that my assumptions were correct. By googling "site:nih.gov methamphetamine neuroprotective", I was led to the following: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24333768 and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25724762

Surprisingly it is neuroprotective following stroke.

**So, putting all this into account, is it possible that meth actually heals wounds and diseases (while at the same time inducing neurotoxicity)?**

This assumption came to me because I have an aggressive cat and whenever I'm high on meth I noticed how wounds from a cat scratch would heal within a day or two instead of a week.

Comment: I suggest performing an empirical experiment: make some kind of repeatable, standardized wound, and measure how long it takes to "heal" (you will have to define an endpoint) on 3-5 occasions, then do the same while the analyte chemical is present in the biological system of interest (it makes it hard for even the most open-minded scientists to take an investigation seriously when it includes the words "high on meth"). Compare the ~5 control trials and ~5 experimental trials and perform statistics to determine if there is a "statistically significant" difference.

Comment: [Impact of methamphetamine on infection and immunity](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fnins.2014.00445/full) [Methamphetamine alters blood brain barrier protein expression in mice, facilitating central nervous system infection by neurotropic Cryptococcus neoformans.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3719895/) There may be short term benefits but long term use would lead to more overwhelming negative effects.